# Checking if JValue is null

Tags: c#, json, json.net, nullable

Why this code doesn't run, I want to check if JSON contains integer for key `PurchasedValue` or not? () :

```
public PropertyInfo(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken jToken)
{
    this.jToken = jToken;
    int PurchasedValue = (int)(jToken["PurchasedValue"].Value ?? 0);
}
```

the error is :

```
Error CS0019: Operator `??' cannot be applied to operands of type `method group' and `int' (CS0019)
```

Comment: It's of Newtonsoft JSON.NET

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From my understanding `jToken["PurchasedValue"]` is a nullable value.
You have to use

```
int PurchasedValue = (int)(jToken["PurchasedValue"]?? 0);
```

`nullableObj.Value` can be only used without error only when there is a value for the `nullableObj`

Otherwise You can use like

```
int PurchasedValue = jToken["PurchasedValue"].HasValue?jToken["PurchasedValue"].Value: 0;
```

This May not even need type casting

Comment: PurchasedValue = (int)(jToken["PurchasedValue"].Type!=JTokenType.Null ? jToken["PurchasedValue"].Value<int>(): 0);

Answer (score 8):

You can compare the token type:

```
var purchasedValueToken = jToken["PurchasedValue"];
int purchasedValue = purchasedValueToken.Type == JTokenType.Null ? 0 : purchasedValueToken.Value<int>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are couple of things here :

The jToken["PurchasedValue"] could return anything so a type check would be preferable.

You can change your code as following:

```
public PropertyInfo(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken jToken)
{
    this.jToken = jToken;
    int PurchasedValue = jToken["PurchasedValue"] is int ? jToken["PurchasedValue"] : 0;
}
```